# Is there a way to automatically generate and export a PDF with VB.NET using Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I just want to save some time and not go through the process of having to press export, name the pdf and choose a folder every time. But I am having a hard time finding a way to automatically export a pdf to a specific folder using vb.net and crystal reports.
I know that if I use `reportdocument.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)` it will automatically print. Is there an equivalent to this, but with exporting a pdf to a specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CRYSTAL_REPORTS,_DEVELOPER_VERSION_FOR_MICROSOFT_VISUAL_STUDIO/0d6684e153174710b8b2eb114bb7f843/45acc0016e041014910aba7db0e91070.html?locale=en-US) it can be achieved like so:

```
reportdocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, exportPath + "Filename.pdf")
```